# Macruby can not load dispatch gem in application

Tags: rubygems, macruby, dispatch

I want to use Dispatch gem in MacRuby to use concurrency in my app. But I got into a tricky problem with this. I tried to install Dispatch gem via 'gem install dispatch', via 'macgem install dispatch', via sudo both previous variants.
But if I try to run my app via 'sudo macrake' I always get:
  rake aborted!
  no such file to load -- dispatch

What am I doing wrong? Are there some part that I miss in using gems with macruby?

P.S. I have require 'rubygems' in my rakefile...

Here is macgem env output:
macgem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.20
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2008-06-03 patchlevel 0) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/DarkDeny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
  - RUBYGEMS PREFIX: /Users/DarkDeny/Projects/SpaceInspector
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.12/usr/bin/macruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/DarkDeny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
    - universal-macruby-0.12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/DarkDeny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
     - /Users/DarkDeny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Why you used `gem install`, but not `macgem install`?  Please show output of `macgem env`

Comment: I used both gem and macgem. Nothing helps.

Comment: when you call `macrake` command using `sudo` your environment variables are not exported automatically.  Try without `sudo` first.

Comment: macgem install dispatch
       ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `to_str' for #<Errno::EAGAIN:0x400919240>

Comment: macrake quietly exits, btw.